# How to map through an object with array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object which has an array of objects and 2 other key-value pairs.
I get stuck on how to display the object values. I got an error showing `'TypeError: obj.map is not a function`.

This is my code

```
import React from 'react'

function MapObj() {

    const obj = {
        items: [
          {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Pizza'
        },
        {
         id: 2,
         title: 'Hot-Dog'
       }
       ],
        total: 200,
        isEmpty: false
      };

  const mappedObj = obj.map(item => {
      return (
       <>
         <div key={item.items.id}>
          <h2>{item.items.title}</h2>
         </div>
        <p>{item.total}</p>
        <p>{item.isEmpty}</p>
       </>
      )
  })

  return (
    <div style={{textAlign: 'center', color: 'maroon'}}>
        {mappedObj}
    </div>
  )
}

export default MapObj
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `map` does not exist on an `object` but only on an `array`.

Try to use `map`  on `object.items` instead on the object directly. Also you can access the property using `item.id` for example directly.

Like this:

```
import React from 'react'

function MapObj() {

    const obj = {
        items: [
          {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Pizza'
        },
        {
         id: 2,
         title: 'Hot-Dog'
       }
       ],
        total: 200,
        isEmpty: false
      };

  const mappedObj = obj.items.map(item => {
      return (
       <>
         <div key={item.id}>
          <h2>{item.title}</h2>
         </div>
        <p>{obj.total}</p>
        <p>{obj.isEmpty}</p>
       </>
      )
  })

  return (
    <div style={{textAlign: 'center', color: 'maroon'}}>
        {mappedObj}
    </div>
  )
}

export default MapObj
```

Comment: I used this as the obj value  {"items":[{"id":"61f5530ffa13c013c514cc5f","title":"Shrimps"}],"isEmpty":false,"total":1500}  which is gotten from my localstorage, but am still getting 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')'

Comment: The error you get means that the object you call `map` on is not defined. So check the localstorage if you are getting the correct data.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When i console.log my localstorage i get the object {"items":[{"id":"61f5530ffa13c013c514cc5f","title":"Shrimps"}],"isEmpty":false,"total":1500}, and when I use the hardcoded object value in my code it works as expected, but when i dynamically get the object value using  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shop')!); , it keeps showing 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')' . Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: How do you store your object in localStorage? You should also show where and how you retrieve the value in react.

Comment: When I console.log the local storage value, it outputs the exact object above which I am trying to map. And this is how I retrieve the value from the local storage. JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( 'item' )! );

Comment: Since you are using react there are plenty of possibilites what could cause the problem .. Open a new question OR edit the question for showcasing how exactly you **store** and **save** the values to localStoage

Comment: Thank you for your tip, I found out that the issue is from how I saved the values to localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply the method map on an object. Try applying it on the array inside the object:

```
const mappedObj = obj.items.map(item => {
      return (
       <>
         <div key={item.id}>
          <h2>{item.title}</h2>
         </div>
        <p>{obj.total}</p>
        <p>{obj.isEmpty}</p>
       </>
      )
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Object don't have `map`

You can use this approach :

```
const mappedObj = obj.items.map(item => {
      return (
       <>
         <div key={item.id}>
          <h2>{item.title}</h2>
         </div>
       </>
      )

return (
    <div style={{textAlign: 'center', color: 'maroon'}}>
        {mappedObj}

        <p>{obj.items.total}</p>
        <p>{obj.items.isEmpty}</p>
    </div>
  )
```

And you can also loop the object with `for in loop`